# rspec password test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out. I'm not sure why, but for some reason my password digest hash isn't matching up. When I run the test I get this error:

```
expected: password_digest: "$2a$04$cDKhuWzsZuW8Gm4t5fJjpu6rmbwh10ZAt2Yae.BO0iuD...">
got: password_digest:      "$2a$04$jwfHjoLI0RpDIAEr9SMKGOZqeH.J5ILOkzalKCYQdDW4...">
```

I should note that the application code works just fine. I can call create a user and authenticate it with user.authenticate('foobar') in the console and it'll work as expected. I have dropped and redone my database numerous times with the same results.

Here's my test: https://gist.github.com/DavidVII/f190d1f1e114234bb7d7#file-user_spec-rb-L107

The part that is failing is the line 107. I'm using bcrypt with `has_secure_password`.

I'm really new to testing and would really appreciate some details on how to go about getting this test to pass.

My password hash just keep being recreated each time and I don't know how to get it to stop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out @user was being generated with each run. I installed the database_cleaner gem and now I've got it working wonderfully.